# understanding the user input using dictionary in python

Tags: python, user-input

#### I am looking for a solution to understand user input

my solution is to have a variable dictionary but probably there is a better way of doing it.

here's my take:

I have a list of key words that should trigger some pieces of code
every item in list has a prime number value so if I multiply them there will be no matches and a unique number will execute only one action (it's messy and I was unable to put it to work :D)

```py
keywords = {"open": 2
            "close": 3
            "door" : 5
            "don't": -1}
actions = input("/ ").lower()
if actions in keywords:
    print(keywords.get(actions)) # I use print for display purposes
```

##### so let's say user input is "open" => 2 get's printed

##### but if i have 2 key words "open door" => nothing gets done

(because "open door" is one whole thing which is not on a list)

I am looking for a solution to this issue i.e. (how to separate different words in the input e.g. if the input is "please open the door for me" or "open the damn door" how will the program search for key words in that input moreover how will it take all the separate values and multiply it ???

#### if you have a better solution please help out

p.s if there is solution to my method I want to know it to

Comment: Split the user input into a list of words, and iterate over that list, looking for each of those individual words in the dictionary.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: You seem to believe that `actions = input("/ ").lower()` will assign a list of words to variable `actions`. It does not. It assigns the string entered by the user, converted to lowercase, to the variable `actions`. Where did you get the idea the string entered by the user would be split into words? Programming is probably not the best profession for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user22309639 You said:

> how will it take all the separate values and multiply it ???

### Step0 :

In the dictionary you forget the comma.

```
keywords = {
    "open": 2,
    "close": 3,
    "door" : 5,
    "don't": -1
}
```

### Step1 :

You split the result:

```
user_input = input("/ ").lower().split()
```

***Details*** :

Split is a function that change a string to a list, and if you give the function a parameter, it will cut the string in piece when the function see the parameter. If you do not give a parameter the split() function will cut the string when it see a space.

***Example :***

```
dot = "0.0.0.0"
print(dot.split("."))
#You will see on the terminal : ['0', '0', '0', '0']
```

### Step2 :

You declare a variable that is going to containt the multiplication result:

```
cpt = 1
```

### Step3 :

You make a loop to see if the index content of the list(user_input) are equal to a key of the dictionary(keywords) :

```
for action in user_input:
    if action in keywords:
        #cpt = cpt * keywords[action]
        cpt*=keywords[action]
```

### Final Code:

```
keywords = {
    "open": 2,
    "close": 3,
    "door" : 5,
    "don't": -1
}

user_input = input("/ ").lower().split()

cpt=1
for action in user_input:
    if action in keywords:
        cpt*=keywords[action]
```

Comment: You can use `functools.reduce` to make this a little more concise! `functools.reduce(operator.mul, user_input.lower().split(), initializer=1)` Depending on your familiarity with functional patterns, however, that might be harder to read and reason about.

Answer (score 2):

Before searching for keywords in the input, you could create a list of actions by splitting the user input at spaces.

```
keywords = {"open": 2,
            "close": 3,
            "door" : 5,
            "don't": -1}
user_input = input("/ ").lower()
actions = user_input.split(' ')

for action in actions:
    if action in keywords:
        print(keywords.get(action)) # I use print for display purposes
```

Then you could do what you described if you swap the print line to multiplication and then you continue processing from there.